# python:Move a specific word at the end of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

i learn python and i do a discord bot. I have some difficulties to print the element after "anivia". i cant say if there is "anivia" in the 'texte' and i can count him but i don't know how to print the element after "anivia", if someone can help me please :)

```
@bot.command()
async def counter(ctx, *champion):
    champion = " ".join(champion)
    url = "https://u.gg/lol/champions/"
    counter = "/counter"
    uurl = url + champion + counter
    await ctx.send(uurl)

    import urllib.request
    with urllib.request.urlopen(uurl) as response:
        texte = response.read()
    if ("anivia" in str(texte)):
        print("Le mot existe !")
    else:
        print("Le mot n'existe pas!")
    test = str(texte)

    z = test.count('anivia')
    print(z)
```

I can count 9 "anivia" with z and i want to print the next element after all the anivia (example: " hello i m anivia and i like anivia test": **and**, **test**).

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses an auxiliary variable to mark when the next word needs to be printed.

```
test_string = "Hello, I am anivia on mid or anivia jungle"

do_print = False
splitted = test_string.split()
for word in splitted:
    if do_print:
        do_print = False
        print(word)
    if word == "anivia":
        do_print = True
```

Output:

```
on
jungle
```

Comment: No problem, I recommend checking out the regexp answer @ricekab gave you and remember to upvote and accept the answer you found most helpful :)

Comment: AHHHHH I DONT UNDERSTAND STACKOVERFLOWWWWWWWWWW

Comment: There is a tick mark next to each answer and you can click it to accept the answer. Also, there is an upvote/downvote button next to each answer and clicking it will upvote/downvote the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with regular expressions (regex), this becomes very simple:

```
import re

# This pattern will capture the first word that comes after "anivia"
pattern = r'anivia (\w+)'

# Using this string as our example input
example_string = "anivia first anivia second and finally anivia third"

results = re.findall(pattern, example_string)

print(results)  # Output: ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, the those solution works with strings (i tried too with regex) but

```
    do_print = False
    splitted = test_string.split()
    for word in splitted:
        # print(word)

        if do_print:
            do_print = False
        if word == "anivia":
            do_print = True
    
    test_string = str(texte)

    do_print = False
    splitted = test_string.split()
    for word in splitted:
        # print(word)

        if do_print:
            do_print = False
            # print(word)
        if word == "champion_id":
            do_print = True`` 

on the first case i have the ("on" and the "jungle") but with my str(texte), that's doesn't fonction :S.
 If someone knows why, the 2 test_strings are "strings" 

 ^^ ty for your answers :)
```

Comment: You can add comments under answers to ask for clarification or if something didn't work. That way you also notify that person so they can (hopefully) respond sooner. Could you explain what part of the regex solution didn't work for you?